# mongoose not updating doc inside async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a doc inside `async.eachSeries`. But it does not update and I am not getting any error. See the code below.

I want to update the oldest doc, namely field `LastDatePresent` in that doc with the `newest` date present in both docs. So I have two duplicate docs based on `UrlLink`, and I want to update the oldest doc based on `_id` with the newest date in both docs. Example docs:

```
{
   "_id": "older id", 
   "Date": ISODate("2017-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
   "UrlLink": "www.myurl.com"
   "LastDatePresent": ISODate("2017-08-30T00:00:00.000Z") //Should be updated to "LastDatePresent": ISODate("2017-08-31T00:00:00.000Z")
}
{
   "_id": "newer id",
   "Date": ISODate("2017-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
   "UrlLink": "www.myurl.com"
   "LastDatePresent": ISODate("2017-08-31T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Thankful for any suggestions:

```
async.eachSeries(aggres, function(member, callback2) {
    myTable.find({
        "UrlLink": member.UrlLink,
        "Date": member.Date,
    }, {
        _id: 1,
        UrlLink: 1,
        Date: 1,
        LastDatePresent: 1
    }, {
        sort: {
            '_id': 1
        }
    }, function(err, post) {
        var latestdate = post[0].LastDatePresent > post[1].LastDatePresent ? post[0].LastDatePresent : post[1].LastDatePresent;        
        myTable.update({
                "UrlLink": post[0].UrlLink,
                "Date": post[0].Date
            }, {
                $set: {
                    LastDatePresent: latestdate //NOT UPDATING HERE!
                }
            },
            function(err, result) {
                console.log("saving DATA");
                callback2();
            });
    });
}, function(err) {
   console.log("DONE");
});
```

Comment: You probably need to show some sample data here and demonstrate what you expect to happen. Not really sure why you would be reading data from a collection by one set of criteria and updating via another set. But walking though the example with data should make that clear. Problem is your question does not clearly show "why" something should match and update. So that's what you need to demonstrate. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the suggestion, but the only problem is that I cant update the doc. Everything else works. Very strange.

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited according to your comment.

Comment: No you have not. And you should need to spend a few minutes more producing what was specifically asked for. It's in your best interests, because unless you can clear that up I see it likely that your question will get closed.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, forgot to update... Pls see now

Comment: Are you trying to update one or many records also in each iteration? What exactly happens when you run it? Does it hang or go all the way to the `DONE` statement?

Comment: @Mikey please see edit again. No error, everything goes smooth besides that `LastDatePresent` is not updated in doc with the oldest `_id`.

Comment: That makes it clear. Because your update does not use `"muti": true` and the conditions match two documents. Only one of them ( likely the one you are reading from ) is actually being updated. What you probably should do instead is use the `_id` value from the found document from and target the single update at that "one" document match instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried with `_id` as well but it did not update. I tried `myTable.update({"_id": new ObjectId(post[0]._id)})`. Also I sort by `_id` before updating, to get the oldest id, so it should actually update the doc it gets in `find` query.

Comment: Go back and "try with _id" again. I think you will find that if you check that you are actually doing what you think you are doing then the updates are correct. If you're not sure, then actually check the `result` and it will tell you if the document was matched and modified or not. But you either need to make sure you match the document you want to update, or you apply `"multi"` to ensure both documents are updated.

Comment: Also fix this line `var latestdate = ( post[0].LastDatePresent.valueOf() > post[1].LastDatePresent.valueOf()) ? post[0].LastDatePresent : post[1].LastDatePresent;`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks Neil, I will do that.